# findViewById() from custom view return null

Tags: android, android-activity, view, findviewbyid

It seem similar to other questions but I doesn't found solutions. I have a layout defined by xml file:

**main_layout.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ... >

       <package.CustomView
       ... >
       </package.CustomView>

       <TextView
       android:id="@+id/text_view"
       ... >
       </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

where CustomView extends SurfaceView.

In onCreate I have setContentView(R.layout.main_layout). Now, If I want to inflate, for example, the TextView in the activity I have to add after setContentView(...)

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewbyId(R.id.text_view);
```

and all works fine. But if I put this line in a method of my CustomView I got a null pointer. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById()` will traverse only the given view and its children. It will not find sibling views. Your textview is a sibling to the custom view, not a child view.

In an activity, the root view where `findViewById()` traversal starts is the activity window (`Activity.findViewById()`). In a view, it is the view itself (`View.findViewById()`).

Answer (score 0):

Understanding helpful explanation above I would like to give an easy way to find a view by its ID from `CustomViews`:

```
(Activity)getContext()).findViewById(R.id.youViewToBeFound);
```

inside your `CustomView` class.

This code must be run AFTER constructor code e.g. inside `onAttachedToWindow()`